# Where is `_init_completion` defined?

Tags: bash, arch-linux

I'm on Manjaro Linux.

I'm trying to customize my bash completion but most of the completions I've got (in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/` & from [github](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/tree/master/completions) have a line like `_init_completion || return`. However, upon trying `_<TAB>`, there is no `_init_completion` function, and I can't find it in any of my completion files.

This `_init_completion` seems to be used by most bash completion scripts but doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. Googling "bash _init_completion" doesn't return a clear result with a file defining the function either.

Where can I get the `_init_completion` function?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/229038/490855

Answer (score 2):

At least on my Debian 10 system, it is defined in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`, and sourced from there by `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`, which is in turn sourced by `/etc/profile`.

Those files are provided in Debian by a separate `bash-completion` package. Its upstream source is [the very same Github repository you linked](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/bash_completion#L728), not in the `completions` sub-directory but at the top level of the repository.